# DAX: Necesito que CALCULATE no se afecte por filtos de la base de datos

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Tengo el siguiente calculo en una base de datos:

`SUM:=CALCULATE(SUM([Data]),FILTER(ALL(Table[Month]),[Month]=[CURRENTMONTH]))`

Donde
**[Data]** es numerico ,**[Month]** es fecha (estan los 12 meses del año),
**[CURRENTMONTH]** es un calculo que de acuerdo con la fecha de hoy identifica el mes actual

En esa misma tabla tengo una columna con los dias del mes **[day]**

Necesito que el calculo no se ve afectado por los filtros de la base de datos es decir que necesito que la suma sea el total del mes aunque filtre por un solo día del mes.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola Luis, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Listo en español

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar la función `ALLEXCEPT` que "[elimina todos los filtros de contexto en la tabla, excepto los filtros que se aplican a las columnas especificadas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634795.aspx)".

quedaría la formula:

`SUM:=CALCULATE(SUM([Data]),ALLEXCEPT(Table[Month],[Month]=[CURRENTMONTH]))`